# _locale in form login Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I need to rewrite firewall to use _locale. For now I have this config and it is working fine except one thing. On login_check I'm losing _locale part of the url and then it reroutes to default locale. How can I modify it to use _locale in login_check?

```
        client_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/client
        anonymous: ~
        provider: clients
        form_login:
            login_path: /client/login
            check_path: /client/login_check
            username_parameter: login
            password_parameter: password
            default_target_path: /client/cabinet
        logout:
            intention:            logout
            path:                 /client/logout
            target:               /
            success_handler:      ~
            invalidate_session:   true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with localized firewall URLs, you usually configure the firewall with routes, not urls:

```
...
form_login:
    login_path: login
    check_path: login_check
    default_target_path: cabinet
    ...
```

Then in your routing config you just localize the URL's:

```
...
login:
    path:      /{_locale}/login
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBundle:Controller:login }

login_check:
    path:      /{_locale}/login_check
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBundle:Controller:loginCheck }

cabinet:
    path:      /{_locale}/cabinet
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBundle:Controller:cabinet }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this should work. In your security.yml:

```
form_login:
  login_path: login
  check_path: login_check
  always_use_default_target_path: true
  default_target_path: /client/cabinet
```

and check_path definie in routing.yml in your bundle:

```
login:
  pattern: /
  defaults: { ... }

login_check:
   pattern: /login_check
```